# How to insert into SQLite database with C#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, asynchronous, xamarin

I am fetching my data in SQLite C# in Xamarin app like that:

```
public Task<List<Doctors>> ReadDoctors()
{
    return db.Table<Doctors>().ToListAsync();
}
```

How can I insert into doctors table in a same manner?
I tried

```
var newDoc = new Doctors { Name = "John Doe" };

string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                  "healthcare.db");

SQLiteAsyncConnection db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

await db.Doctors.AddAsync(newDoc);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But methods AddAsync are not found SaveChangesAsync and Doctors in db is also not found.

How can I just insert into table somehow in a similar manner like i am selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)?  If so, this is covered in the [docs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#asynchronous-api)

```
var newDoc = new Doctors { Name = "John Doe" };
await db.InsertAsync(newDoc);
```

Comment: I dont know why but I couldnt find it. Thanks.